# Как сделать так, чтобы программа решала математическое выражение, вводимое пользователем?

Tags: java, строки, double

допустим у пользователь вводит "cosx/sinx+1",
x нам известен (к примеру x = 5)
Суть в том, что нельзя просто привести это всё к строке вида Math.cos(a)/Math.sin(a)+1, а затем передать формулу численной переменной, но как сделать иначе я не представляю

Comment: Нужно написать или взять готовый интерпретатор и скормить ему выражение.

Answer (score 0):

Могу посоветовать интерпретатор Basic-а.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/obasic/

Правда это не Ява, а С++. Но, по слухам, из Явы можно вызвать код С++. :-)

Comment: есть встроенный интерпретатор js...

Comment: @Stranger in the Q В Яве есть встроенный интерпретатор яваскрипта?

Comment: угу, начиная с 7 или 8 точно не помню

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/java-nashorn

Comment: `System.out.println(new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("js").eval("Math.sin(0.5)/Math.cos(0.5)+2"))`

Comment: @Stranger in the Q А результат-то как из интерпретатора js обратно в Яву возвращать? Печатать и опять текст парсить?

Comment: да, а это проблема?

Comment: @Stranger in the Q В простом случае может и не проблема. А если что посложнее и несколько результатов? Да и сама постановка вопроса странная: нужен парсер для формул, но чтобы получить результат снова нужен парсер для результатов.

Comment: по этому я и не предлагаю это как ответ, есть такая возможность, а переходить на темную сторону или нет это уже решать не мне =)

Comment: однако бизнес иногда требует такие решения

Comment: а так - добавить к этому `JSON.stringify` со стороны `js` и `Jackson` со стороны `java` и уже получите объекты.